# Передача события от потомка родителю QGraphicsItemGroup

Tags: c++, qt

Пишу игру пазлы. Если пазл подходит к другому пазлу, то объединяю QGraphicsItemGroup. Когда я нажимаю на родителя чтобы переместить, то родитель передает событие потомку (в общем-то, перемещаем все пазлы, которые находятся в группе), но если сделать наоборот, т.е нажать на потомка и переместить, то ничего не происходит (потомок почему-то не передает событие родителю и сам потомок не реагирует на событие мыши).
Что нужно сделать, чтобы потомок передавал событие родителю?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, Вы обрабатываете нажатие через переопределение обработчика события? Если да, то попробуйте в обработчике принудительно передать событие дальше [The Event System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/eventsandfilters.html) . Посмотрите раздел **Event Handlers**. Мне кажется, конструкция типа следующей поможет Вам

```
void MyCheckBox::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
        //Тут Ваша обработка
         ......
        // pass on other buttons to base class
        QCheckBox::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```